# ASP.NET DropDownList Duplicate Values from Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My Database is Like This.

```
Vehicle Make |  Vehicle Model
-----------------------------
Toyota       | AQUA
HONDA        | FIT
Toyota       | Prius
```

`DropDownList1`, Populates Like this.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT VehicleMake FROM VehicleDB", con);
    adapter.Fill(subjects);

    con.Open();


    DropDownList1.DataSource = subjects;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "VehicleMake";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "VehicleMake";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    con.Close();

}
```

But since i have duplicate data(2 Toyota's), it shows them in the DropDownList too.

Is it possible to filter and only have 1 Toyota?

-PS

I need it added my database, as there are may more Vehicle makes too add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT VehicleMake FROM VehicleDB", con);
```

You might want to add an `ORDER BY` too:

```
string sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT VehicleMake 
               FROM VehicleDB
               ORDER BY VehicleMake ASC";
using(var  adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You can change your query to "SELECT VehicleMake FROM VehicleDB where VehicleMake <> 'FIT Toyota'" and changing query is not an option for you there then you can do something like this

```
var subjects= ds.Tables["VehicleDB"];
adresse.DefaultView.RowFilter = "VehicleMake LIKE '%TEST%'";

DropDownList1.DataSource = subjects;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "VehicleMake";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "VehicleMake";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

and even this wont work Apply LINQ - for loop for the datatable